# interface locationProps, Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I am passing a user object through the `useNavigation` object like:

```
 let navigate = useNavigate();

    const showUser = (user: UserProp): void => {
        navigate('view', { state: user });
    }
```

once i landed to the `view` component, I am trying to get the value from the location. but getting error.
here is the code :

```
interface locationProps {
    state: { user: UserProp }
}

export default function UserView() {
    const { state } = useLocation<locationProps>();
    return (
        <h1>{state && state.user.name}</h1>
    )
}
```

getting an error as `interface locationProps, Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.`

Answer (score 5):

It works for me:

```
export interface UserProp {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    username: string;
    email: number;
    address: AddressProps
}
```

after the declaration of the interface i used the same as:

`const data = useLocation().state as UserProp;` to get my all data.
thanks every one!!